# Jest React Native FlatList onViewableItemsChanged on executing inside functions while testing using Jest

Tags: react-native, unit-testing, jestjs, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

I am using the onViewableItemsChanged prop from Flatlist. The functionality is working as expected, but when I perform unit test on the same I can see that the function is being called but the statements inside the function are not being executed when performing unit testing.

**app.js**

```
  const onViewableItemsChanged = React.useCallback(
    ({ viewableItems, changed, viewabilityConfig }) => {
      setActiveIndex(viewableItems);
    },
    [],
  );

  const setActiveIndex = (activeViews) => {
    if (activeViews?.length !== 0) {
      let index = activeViews[0]?.index;
      setActiveViewIndex(index);
    }
  };

  return(
    <View>
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={checkedInPersonsList}
          horizontal
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          style={{ flexGrow: 0 }}
          contentContainerStyle={{
            paddingHorizontal: containerHorizontalPadding,
          }}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) =>
            renderFlatList(item, index, checkedInPersonsList)
          }
          //   onScroll={onScroll}
          onViewableItemsChanged={onViewableItemsChanged}
          viewabilityConfig={{
            itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 92,
          }}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={() => (
            <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 10 }} />
          )}
          testID={'PaxScrollerFlatList.test'}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  )
```

**app.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react-native';
import PaxScroller from './index';

describe('Pax Scroller', () => {
  test('Scroll Flatlist Horizontal', () => {
    const { getAllByTestId, getByTestId } = render(
      <PaxScroller checkedInPersonsList={list} />,
    );
    
    let fList = getByTestId('PaxScrollerFlatList.test');
    fireEvent.scroll(fList, {
      nativeEvent: {
        contentSize: { height: 600, width: 600 },
        contentOffset: { y: 0, x: 0 },
        layoutMeasurement: { height: 100, width: 400 },
      },
    });
  });
}
```

After Executing the test case, I can see in the test coverage that onViewableItemsChanged is being called but the inside statements are not getting executed. Is there a way where this statements highlighted in red can be executed?

[image]

Please help me execute the inside statements.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that, if you want to trigger the handler for `onViewableItemsChanged` in a FlatList, you'd have to:

- Use `fireEvent.scroll` to simulate a scroll event
- Pass it layout dimensional data

Like:

```js
const eventData = {
  nativeEvent: {
    contentOffset: {
      y: 500,
    },
    contentSize: {
      // Dimensions of the scrollable content
      height: 500,
      width: 100,
    },
    layoutMeasurement: {
      // Dimensions of the device
      height: 100,
      width: 100,
    },
  },
};

fireEvent.scroll(screen.getByTestId('flat-list'), eventData);
```

See [these docs](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-testing-library/docs/api/#on-a-flatlist).

This may be a case where end-to-end testing is better suited.

Answer (score 0):

To fire `onViewableItemsChanged` you must first simulate a set of `layout` events to provide the list internals with the necessary dimensions.

1. Simulate the `layout` event for each of the list items.
2. Simulate the `layout` event for the list element itself.
3. Wait some time. Even if you don't use `minimumViewTime` there is some async orchestration happening behind the scenes.

```js
const ITEM_HEIGHT = 100;
const GAP = 10;

const listElement = getByTestId('PaxScrollerFlatList.test');
const listItems = getAllByTestId(/^PaxScrollerFlatList.item/);

// 1. Simulate layout for each of list items
listItems.forEach((item, index) => {
  const isLastItem = index === listItems.length - 1;
  const y = index * ITEM_HEIGHT;
  const height = isLastItem ? ITEM_HEIGHT : ITEM_HEIGHT + GAP;

  fireEvent(item, 'layout', {
    nativeEvent: {
      layout: { height, y },
    },
  });
});

// 2. Simulate layout for the list element itself
fireEvent(listElement, 'layout', {
  nativeEvent: {
    layout: {height: (ITEM_HEIGHT + GAP) * listItems.length - GAP},
  },
});

// 3. Let async orchestration happen
jest.advanceTimersByTime(100);

fireEvent.scroll( ... )
```